# Cant set OutputType for PowerPoint Print with VBScript

Tags: vbscript, powerpoint

I am able to open a pptx file via vbscript and print it, but I can't for the life of me get the `OutputType` set. I continuallly get this error no matter my formatting, I even copied direct from Microsoft docs. Any idea whats wrong?>

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.printoptions

Error:

```
C:\Windows\system32>cscript.exe C:\tmp\print_ppt.vbs
Microsoft (R) Windows Script Host Version 5.812
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\tmp\print_ppt.vbs(26, 9) Microsoft PowerPoint 2016: PrintOptions.OutputType : Invalid enumeration value.
```

Code:

```
Dim objPPT
Dim objPresentation
Dim objPrintOptions

Set objPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
objPPT.Visible = True

'Presentations.Open "filename", boolReadOnly, boolOpenUntitled, boolWithWindow
Set objPresentation = objPPT.Presentations.Open("C:\tmp\test.pptx",msoTrue,,msoFalse)

Set objPrintOptions = objPresentation.PrintOptions
objPrintOptions.PrintInBackground = False
   'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.printoptions.outputtype
'objPrintOptions.OutputType = ppPrintOutputSixSlideHandouts
'objPresentation.PrintOut


With objPresentation 
    With .PrintOptions 
        .NumberOfCopies = 2 
        .Collate = False 
        .PrintColorType = ppPrintColor 
        .PrintHiddenSlides = True 
        .FitToPage = True 
        .FrameSlides = True 
        .OutputType = ppPrintOutputSlides 
    End With 
    .PrintOut 
End With

objPresentation.PrintOptions.PrintInBackground = True
objPPT.Quit
Set objPPT = nothing
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but VBA isn't VBScript. What works in VBA is not guaranteed to run in VBScript because the former is an extension language for MS applications and VBScript is a system-level scripting language.

Comment: However, you could try adding "//D" to the end of your invocation string which would then launch Visual Studio and allow you to see what's failing and maybe work out what to do next. E.g. C:\Windows\system32>cscript.exe C:\tmp\print_ppt.vbs //D

Comment: I think it might be something to do with "named" vs "positional" arguments. I find VBScript works better when I can use `(dostuff, value)` vs `Command Value:=True` but seems not everything works w/ `positional` and I'm having a hard time translating, also not sure if thats the problem at all.

Comment: Before you go any further, declare msoTrue and msoFalse because VBScript hasn't a clue what they are. In Visual Studio I type in "msoTrue" in the "Immediate Window" and get "Empty"

Comment: `msoBool` is a positional argument to `Presentations.Open`. It doesn't get `Declared`.

Comment: Another suggestion: Get VBSEdit from Adersoft https://www.vbsedit.com

Comment: `Error: PrintOptions.OutputType : Invalid request.  This method or property is no longer supported by this version of PowerPoint.`

Comment: If I comment out the .OutputType line, my printer spits out slides.

Comment: hence the question

Comment: Use the numeric value of outputtype from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744185.aspx

Comment: @Flakes U are the Flake! Worked Straight away. Write up an answer? Anything I can learn to avoid this moving forward. I'd hate to admit how long I screwed with this, and the worst/annoying part is I consider myself very familiar with VBA but things just 'sorta' work the same in VBScript.

Comment: Glad it worked. Most named constants like this are not available in vbs. You need to either define them with the corresponding numeric values or use the values as such. Please add an answer yourself, linking to the ms document. I am just a flake:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBA and VBScript are similar obviously, but different. This was a good read for me tonight to start seeing some of the "minor" differences which can give you a headache if you are familiar w/ VBA and expect VBScript to work the same.

[https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/vbscript-in-a/1565927206/ch01s03.html#:~:text=VBScript%20is%20a%20subset%20of%20the%20Visual%20Basic%20for%20Applications%20language.&text=VBScript%20is%20an%20untyped%20language,variables%20in%20VBScript%20are%20variants](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/vbscript-in-a/1565927206/ch01s03.html#:%7E:text=VBScript%20is%20a%20subset%20of%20the%20Visual%20Basic%20for%20Applications%20language.&text=VBScript%20is%20an%20untyped%20language,variables%20in%20VBScript%20are%20variants).

Specifcally the part about how `VBScript does not support named arguments.` This is a similar situation where the propertity will work with VBScript, but the sytax in VBA has multiple options and only one in VBScript will work.

In this case it was using the numerical value.

Another example is my line w/

```
    'Presentations.Open "filename", boolReadOnly, boolOpenUntitled, boolWithWindow
    Set objPresentation = objPPT.Presentations.Open("C:\tmp\test.pptx",msoTrue,,msoFalse)
```

This is using `positional` arguments vs `named` value pairs.

Here is where I found the numerical version for the option, now to script some logic into my script so end users can pass an argument like `4` and expect `4Slides/Page`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/PowerPoint.PpPrintOutputType

```
With objPresentation 
    With .PrintOptions 
        .PrintInBackground = False
       'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/PowerPoint.PpPrintOutputType
       'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.printoptions.outputtype
       .OutputType = 8 
    End With 
    '.PrintOut 
   .PrintOptions.PrintInBackground = True
End With
```